# collecting grouped output into a named list in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

How could I collect this table into the list below?

```
df<-tibble(name = c("ageThenCode", "ageThenCode", "ageThenCode", "ageThenCode", "ageThenCode", "ageThenCode", "eduCode", "eduCode", "eduCode", "regioCat", "regioCat", "regioCat", "teltipCode", "teltipCode", "teltipCode"), value = factor(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3")), freq = c(0.042, 0.222, 0.208, 0.222, 0.149, 0.157, 0.155, 0.591, 0.254, 0.373, 0.34, 0.287, 0.271, 0.524, 0.205))

list(
  ageThenCode=c("1"=0.042,  "2"=0.222,  "3"=0.208,  "4"=0.222,  "5"=0.149,  "6"=0.157),
  eduCode=c("1"=.37, "2"=.38, "3"=.25),
  regionCode=c("1"=.373, "2"=.34, "3"=.287),
  teltipCode=c("1"=.271, "2"=.524,"3"=.205)
)
```

I was trying something like this, but couldn't quite make it:

```
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(cat = list(value=freq) ) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = cat)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a named vector and `split` would be the easiest and fast way in `base R`

```
with(df, split(setNames(freq, value), name))
```

---

Or to create the same in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
df %>% 
    split(.$name) %>%
    map(~ deframe(.x[-1]))
```

-output

```
$ageThenCode
    1     2     3     4     5     6 
0.042 0.222 0.208 0.222 0.149 0.157 

$eduCode
    1     2     3 
0.155 0.591 0.254 

$regioCat
    1     2     3 
0.373 0.340 0.287 

$teltipCode
    1     2     3 
0.271 0.524 0.205
```